# how to report inappropiate content in instagram feed using my on ios app

Tags: report, spam

in my iOS application i am showing public Instagram feed .i want to add functionality to report inappropriate  like Instagram   is there any API for Reporting inappropriate content

Comment: Did you find any way to report user?I am also looking for this.